# c# TimeOfDay not between 2 timespans

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, timeofday

Having today's date for example: `DateTime.Now`

And 2 TimeSpan that represents two periods of time

```
DateTime mydate = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse("14:00:00");
TimeSpan end =   TimeSpan.Parse("15:00:00");

// TO DO:
```

How to check that `mydate` time (TimeOfDay) is not between `start` and `end` range.

Basically check if the hours, minutes, seconds are between 14:00 and 15:00 or outside this range.

UPDATE:

The right condition is: `mydate.TimeOfDay <= start || mydate.TimeOfDay >= end`

Comment: `TimeSpan` does not represent *two hours*. It represents period of time, in your case 14 hours and 15 hours, not 2PM and 3PM respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek but it *can* represent time if day, as toby's answer indicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing them seems to work seams to work. `TimeOfDay` is a `TimeSpan` just like `start` and `end`

```
Console.WriteLine(mydate.TimeOfDay <= start || mydate.TimeOfDay >= end);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7P8IOZ)

Comment: The right condition is: `mydate.TimeOfDay <= start || mydate.TimeOfDay >= end`. I'll mark your answer as correct for sending me on the right direction.

Comment: @user2818430 Thank you initially was look if it was inside the interval when i updated forgot to change && into ||

Comment: Usually a range of times is a half open interval `[start,end)`.  To test inside the range, use `time >= start && time < end`.  To test *outside* the range, use `time < start || time >= end`.  You have it close, but are not excluding the start value.